# How to change initial sound level on boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I was just wondering why my Windows 10 computer always sets the sound level to 42 at boot. Even if I change it to 20, every time I start my computer it is back at 42, which is a bit too loud, so I have to set it manually back to 20 every time post-boot.

Does someone else have the same problem; is it related to my Bluetooth headphones? Maybe the headphones are setting it to 42, I don't know.

Any way, is there any way to make sure that it is always at 20 when I boot my PC?

Comment: Have you noticed anything else changing? (time, your settings, etc)

Comment: No, never. Always the sound. It happened for over 2 years now. I never really bothered too much but just thought maybe someone knows how to make it save my settings.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more about your hardware? What system are you using? Do you have any OEM software installed? What type of bluetooth headphones are you using?

Comment: How old is the computer?

Comment: Sound level in Windows 10 does not change from where you left it last.  All computers I have here. Disconnect all USB and Bluetooth devices. Remove and un-pair. Set sound to your liking. Leave all things disconnected, shut down, start up and see. It still be where you left it.